# Removing consecutive duplicates from a string recursively is failing selective test cases

Tags: java, string, recursion

So the task at hand is to remove duplicates from a given string recursively. For example-

Input: aabccba

Output: abcba

My code worked perfectly for this input and 4 out of 6 other test cases. Out of those two, one is giving runtime error while the other is saying that my code is giving a wrong answer. Can someone tell me how I can fix my this?

```
    public static String removeCons(String s) {
    if(s.length() == 1) return s;

    String ans = "";

    String rest = "";

    if(s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(1)) {
        ans += s.charAt(0);
        rest = removeCons(s.substring(2));
    }
    else {
        ans += s.charAt(0);
        rest = removeCons(s.substring(1));
    }

    return ans+rest;
}
```

Comment: `"aabccba".replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1");`

Comment: What are the runtime errors?  What is the 'wrong answer'?

Comment: @Fubar I am running this code on an online platform and unfortunately, that's all the results show.

Comment: @SthitaprajnaMishra Then run it locally so you can **test** it yourself with various inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `aaab` and it will fail (returns `aab`).

When the first two characters are the same, you're keeping the first and skipping the second, without checking if the third (and on) are also the same.

Instead, skip the first, and recurse starting with the second, i.e.

```
if(s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(1)) {
    rest = removeCons(s.substring(1));
}
...
```

The method can then be refactored to:

```
public static String removeCons(String s) {
    if (s.length() <= 1) // fixed to handle empty string too
        return s;
    String ans = removeCons(s.substring(1));
    if (s.charAt(0) != s.charAt(1))
        ans = s.charAt(0) + ans;
    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Andreas's answer, you can write briefly like this:

```
public static String removeCons(String s){
    if (s.length() <= 1) return s;

    if (s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(1)) return removeCons(s.substring(1));

    return s.charAt(0) + removeCons(s.substring(1));
}
```

Comment: If you want *brief*, then compress method body to: `return (s.length() <= 1 ? s : s.substring(0, (s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(1) ? 0 : 1)) + removeCons(s.substring(1)));`. ---- Better yet: `return s.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1");`

Comment: You open a new horizon for me. Do you have any articles about using the replaceall regex, I don't know much about this (sorry about grammar, English is not my native language)

Comment: Well, the regex I stole from a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61482424/removing-consecutive-duplicates-from-a-string-recursively-is-failing-selective-t/61482866?noredirect=1#comment108759800_61482424).

Answer (score 0):

I let you my option and a recursive option.

```
    import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class RemoveDupes {



    public static String removeCons(String s) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Set<Character> chars = new HashSet();
        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            if(!chars.contains(Character.valueOf(c))){
                sb.append(c);
                chars.add(Character.valueOf(c));
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }



    public static String removeConsRecursive(String s) {
        if(s.length() < 2){
            return s;
        }
        String firstLetter = s.substring(0,1);
        String sanitized = s.substring(1).replaceAll(firstLetter,"");
        return firstLetter + removeConsRecursive(sanitized);
    }

    public static void main(String... args){
        System.out.println(removeCons("sasslaereso"));
        System.out.println(removeConsRecursive("sasslaereso"));
    }
```

}